# Passing a big string data from JavaScript to php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a very long string variable(2000+ characters) in JavaScript and I need to pass it to a `Php` page so that I can store it in a Database. Which would be The BEST technique to pass this string variable along with some other data from `JavaScript` to a `Php` page ?

Comment: Do you have a guess for what the average and max sizes would be?  4,000 bytes?  4,000,000,000 bytes?  Is this a string or binary data?

Comment: _BEST_? Dunno, probably JSON + AJAX I'd say...

Comment: just Sting but 2000+ characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$.post('/my/url.php', { 'big': 'aoeuaoeuaoeuaoeuaoeu' } );
```

Of course the contents of the `big` variable will be much bigger. 2000 characters isn't that much. I've posted at least that much with no problem.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Ajax, try posting the data. The encoding is automatic and there is no size limit.

Answer (score 2):

i dont know much but i suggest that using json_encode() you can do it.

Comment: OP wants to send data from javascript to php, not the other way round.